# Training with LIBSVM after extracting high dimensional lbp descriptors using dlib

Tags: c++, libsvm, dlib

I am doing a project on facial expression recognition using dlib to obtain faces and extract descriptors and libsvm to train the obtained data. I am using c++ in Visual Studio Community 2015. So far I have extracted the high dimensional LBP descriptors and now would like to make sense of the features obtained and train using libsvm. I am stuck here because I cannot make sense of the data inside my 'features' vector and further not able to translate that into libsvm's accepted format for training.

Below is the code snippet. Before this almost everything is self-explanatory, I guess.

```js
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> features;//storing features for all images

  std::vector<double> feat;//for a single image

  extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors(img, shape, feat); //dlib's function, storing extracted info in 'feat'

  features.push_back(feat);

  //Now all the info for all the images is stored in 'features' vector. I now need to train the data and make a suitable model using libsvm, precisely RBF kernel.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store as features, as labels to make learning process. LibSVM uses space-based text format. Here is code that can write this format [convert from CSV](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faqfiles/convert.c)

Writing can be like this (untested):

```
ofstream f("data_file");
for (auto img : images) //each image should be 
{
    std::vector<double> feat;
    shape = predictor(img);
    extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors(img, shape, feat);
    double label = is_neutral ? -1.0 : +1.0;
    f << label;
    for (int i = 0; i < feat.size(); ++i)
       if (feat[i] != 0.0)
           f<< " " << i << ":" << feat[i];
    f << endl;
}
```

And if you are using Dlib - you do not need LibSVM - you can make training process with Dlib, [here is an example of SVM training with dlib](http://dlib.net/svm_c_ex.cpp.html)